# Passport validity when traveling from US to india

Tags: passports, india, us-citizens

I'm from USA and both my sons are also citizens. Their ages are 4 and 18 years. Their passports will expire in Jun 2022.

We are planning to go to India in January 2022 for 3 weeks. Can we use the same passport during travel because it needs to be valid for 6 months during travel. We plan to renew it after return from India.

Comment: I think your question may lack some details in order to be able to answer reliably. Try inputting the exact details of your proposed trip here https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true including your planned date of travel, any transit point(s), and the passport expiry dates